# Ajax TreeView

Tags: c#, ajax, treeview

I would like to see if there are any AJAX TreeView controls out there, preferably free. 
Any ideas/experiences?

Thanks

I am using ASP.net 2.0 (web forms, not MVC), c#

EDITED
Someone voted for this question to be closed. Just wonder why? Is it not programming related? To SO creators, if you guys allow every question to be closed, people will stop coming to this site, which is am sure an opposite of what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

funny that you should ask.
i am working right now on making [the tree table](http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-plugins/treeTable/doc/index.html#examples) plugin work with ajax. [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) works with ajax already, but its HUGE.

edit: i just realized that maybe you want something made in C# that does this. you should check if these jquery things might be good enough to write a tag around or something.